# Resources$NotFoundException when Resource exists

Tags: android, exception, android-resources

I am trying to set a drawable to an `ImageView` from inside a custom adapter: `SimpleCursorAdapter`. This is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    switch(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4))){
    case 0:
        Drawable drawable = null;
        try {
            drawable = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(R.drawable.andro_icon);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

But this catches a `Resources$NotFoundException` :

```
02-29 06:39:48.467: W/System.err(13511): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02000c
```

The resource `R.drawable.andro_icon` exists, the code compiles without any problem. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project and restarting eclipse. What's happening here?

Comment: fixed by adding `drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.andro_icon);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Resources.getSystem()` but you want application resources, not system resources. Instead do:

```
context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.andro_icon);
```